# Gradle DSL method not found : 'multiDexEnabled()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I followed the multidex guide at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

But I get this error **Gradle DSL method not found : 'multiDexEnabled()'** . I have updated Android Built Tools , Android Support Repository and Library. Here is my gradle.build file. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
Could not find method multiDexEnabled() for arguments [true] on ProductFlavorDsl_Decorated{name=main, minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=10, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=17, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=-1, renderscriptSupportMode=null, renderscriptNdkMode=null, versionCode=-1, versionName=null, applicationId=test.com.app, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null}.
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.com.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':addThisSDK')
    compile project(':centeredContentButton')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/addthis0.0.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/adxtag2.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_4_0_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/dd-plist.jar')
    compile files('libs/FiksuAndroidSDK_4.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/iqengines-sdk-barcode.jar')
    compile files('libs/irEventTracker-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jolt-core-0.0.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-utils-0.0.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/kooaba-api-v4-java.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be running version 0.14.0 or later of the Android Gradle plugin. See the release notes at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system for details on what's in each release.

Comment: Thanks I updated to latest Android Studio (Canary 0.9.2) and latest Android Gradle Plugin 0.14.2

Comment: @Scott Barta i am using Android studio 1.0 RC 4 but shows me the error as Gradle DSL method not found:'useOldManifestMerger()' i had removed it and run now it shows as  Gradle DSL method not found:'apply()'

Comment: @Manoj start a new question and include your build file details.

Answer (score 18):

I also received this error when I placed the `multiDexEnabled true` command in the wrong location. Make sure it's in the defaultConfig code block:

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the dependencies in your app's gradle file have this lines:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

}

Also, in your global (Project) gradle file, make sure you have the latest gradle version.

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
}
```

In your SDK manager, make sure you have the latest support libraries and repo.

In your AndroidManifest.xml. add the following line:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

You can read the entire documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: So that this is clear, you actually do not need to add that to your manifest if you are extending application. In that case you should add @Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
 }

Comment: Also, this should be selected answer

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

This worked form me.

Comment: In my case my min sdk was 16 due to which multiDexEnabled was not working

Answer (score 0):

In app/build.gridle under defaultConfig add:

```
defaultConfig {
   
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

Then, at the bottom, add this code exactly like this if you dont have dependencies block already:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    ...
}
```

Finally, in `pubspec.yaml` under `dependencies` add:

```
firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
```

After these changes your app should work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` in your Android manifest file in the application element.

Comment: can't even recognize MultiDexApplication as the build.gradle file does not build.